# Cannot get SE login form with tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security

I don't understand why some sites refuse to allow tor users to log in.  I can see why some might resent anonymity, but you aren't anonymous after you log in.

But my issue **today** is that I can't get a login form here on SE.  I don't recall this happening before.  New SE policy?  Bug in the latest tor browser?  Bug in SE?

Click a login link, browser shows all the visual characteristics of going to another page, but then refreshes the page I was already on.  Sign up link works as expected, but I don't want a new account!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about an issue with stackexchange, not Tor. Also because logging in works fine using Tor browser.